# RxJS: Conditional map or mergeMap

Tags: rxjs

If I have a method that sometimes returns a string and sometimes returns a promise that results in a string how can I chain that in my observable?

**Example**

```
function doSomething() {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return 'test';
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => resolve('test'));
}

const example = of(undefined).pipe(
    mergeMap(() => doSomething())
);

const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I would like to always log "test".

Comment: I'd try: `mergeMap(() => await doSomething())`

Comment: Huh, that's an interesting solution. Feels kind of "cheating" to use promises but I guess there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Yeah. The implicit wrapping (and flattening) that comes with promises is not something that I'm especially keen on, but it works here.

Comment: @cartant did you want to add an answer to make it easier for other people to find? If not, I can add one for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of solving the problem would be to make the function passed to `mergeMap` an `async` function and to `await` the return value of `doSomething`, like this:

```js
const example = of(undefined).pipe(
  mergeMap(async () => await doSomething())
);
```

You can do this because `mergeMap` expects the function to return an `ObservableInput` and a promise is a valid `ObservableInput`.

Doing so takes advantage of that fact `await` will accept either a promise or an ordinary value - to which the promise returned by the `async` function will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function doSomething() {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return 'test';
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => resolve('test'));
}

const example = of(undefined)
  .pipe(
    map(() => doSomething()),
    mergeMap(value => value instanceof Promise ? from(value) : from([value]))
  );

const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Not that you asked, but your code is an anti-pattern. Your doSomething method should always return the same value type, in your case, either a string or a promise.